# Laravel storage - access denied (different owner)

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I have two different points which I need to write to the same log file, one is a concole commando file and another is a web controller.

In both cases I use `append` command:

```
Storage::disk('local')->append($logfilePath, $content);
```

The problem is that file is created with permissions 664 (`-rw-r--r--`), so depend on the process that creates the file, the other one cannot write to it.

Is there any way to create file using `Storage` class with permission 666?

Comment: Try this [https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share here the solution I found:

In `config/filesystems.php` I added the following code to `local`:

```
        'local' => [
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0666,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0755,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

When creating a new file I specify the permissions I want the file to have:

```
if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists($logFilePath)) {
    Storage::disk('local')->put($logFilePath, $content, 'public');
} else {
    Storage::disk('local')->append($logFilePath, $content);
}
```

Notice that when using `append`, you cannot set file permissions, even if it is not created yet.